# The 'root.mainloop()' in Tkinter causes an AttributeError

Tags: python, tkinter, attributeerror

In my python code the `root.mainloop()` line causes the error:

> `AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'mainLoop'`

I am on Mac and my code is:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
myLabel1 = Label(root, text = 'My First GUI')
myLabel1.pack()
root.mainLoop()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should replace :

```
root.mainLoop()
```

with

```
root.mainloop()
```

all in small case letters.

Comment: Thanks for that, I hate it when I make stupid errors like that.